# Hint to prove $\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x) = \frac{3 + \cos(4x)}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

Could go from LHS to RHS by adding zero but I need to know how to do this WITHOUT knowing the half-angle formula. So from RHS to LHS, you an expand $\cos4x$ twice. I get as close as
$$\frac{ \cos^4x + \sin^4x + 3(1 - 2\sin^2x\cos^2x)}{4}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{3+\cos4x}{4}&=\frac{3+2\cos^22x-1}{4}=\frac{(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2+1}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin^4x+\cos^4x+(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}{2}\\
&=\sin^4x+\cos^4x
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you know the 1 is $$( sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) )^2$$ instead of just $$sin^2(x) + cos^2(x)$$?

Comment: @user71207 Because $1^2 =1$

Comment: yes but why use $$1^2$$. My first thought was just 1

Comment: @user71207 Because $\sin^4x+\cos^4x$ it's an expression of degree $4$ and $(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2$ with degree $4$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this fully. Could you please expand? Your answer works though, it doesn't work my way with just 1

Comment: @user71207  It's just homogenization. Let $\cos{x}=a$ and $\sin{x}=b$. We know that $a^2+b^2=1$, but we need to get $a^4+b^4$, which is fourth degree. Thus, we'll work with $(a^2+b^2)^2$ because it's fourth degree.

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: @user71207 You are welcome!

Comment: Unrelated question but you seem to be an avid and long time user of this stack exchange. Would you happen to know the level of mathematics most people on this stack exchange happens to be? It seems to me that the average level is REALLY high and topics get discussed with such depth and expertise and I'm just chilling below everyone. I mean it's pretty awesome and inspiring too.

Comment: @user71207 I'm only in high school, like a reasonable amount of people here; hence not all questions are such high level :) I'd say that I'm probably on one of the lowest level of mathematics knowledge here; you can check out my questions/answers to see what sort of level that is.

Comment: I'm in high school too haha I feel exactly the same way. Usually, there are no questions which I might be qualified to help out with, even if I want to help lol

Answer (score 1):

$$\eqalign{1 - 2 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x &= 1 - (1-\cos^2 x) \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x (1 - \sin^2 x)\cr
&= 1 - \cos^2 x + \cos^4 x - \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x\cr
&= \cos^4 x + \sin^4 x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use the Euler formulas
$$
\cos{x} = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}, \quad \sin{x} = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}
$$
and expand the powers on the left side if you are ok with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

To check, you can see if the LHS equals the RHS by using

$$\cos^2 x = \dfrac {\cos 2x + 1}{2} \\ \sin^2 x = \dfrac {1- \cos 2x}{2}$$

Squaring both sides

$$\cos^4 x = \dfrac 14(\cos^2 2x + 2 \cos 2x +1) \\ \sin^4 x = \dfrac 14(1-2 \cos 2x + \cos^2 2x)$$

Adding we get

$$\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = \left(\dfrac 14 {\cos^2 2x} + \dfrac 14 \right) +\left(\dfrac 14 + \dfrac 14 {\cos^2 2x}\right) \\ \cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = \dfrac 12 ({1+\cos^2 2x}) $$

Since $2 \cos^2 2x - 1 = \cos 4x$, $\cos^2 2x = \dfrac 12 ({\cos 4x +1})$ so

$$\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = \dfrac 12 (1 + \dfrac 12 (\cos 4x + 1)) \\ \cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = \dfrac 12 + \dfrac 14 (\cos 4x + 1)$$ or $$\mathbf {\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = \dfrac {3 + \cos 4x}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

```
                   Answer:
```

After Euler formula We know that:

$Cos(x) ^4 = \frac{cos(4x)}{8}+\frac{cos(2x)}{2}+\frac{3}{8}$

And

$sin(x) ^4 =\frac{cos(4x)}{8}-\frac{cos(2x)}{2}+\frac{3}{8}$

So,

$ Cos(x) ^4 +sin(x) ^4=\frac{cos(4x)}{4}+\frac{3}{4} =\frac{cos(4x)+3}{4}$